# Get all record in each group using group by clause

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table like this

```
DepartmentId    EmployeeName
1               A
1               B
2               C
2               D
2               E
```

I want the result to be

```
DepartmentId    EmployeeNames
1               A, B
2               C, D, E
```

and my query I can think of so far is:

```
select DepartmentId, (select EmployeeName for json path) as EmployeeNames
from EmployeeTable
group by DepartmentId
for json path
```

But this one doesn't work out because EmployeeName column is not in the `Group By` clause, the query will give the wrong result if I name that column in the `Group By` clause.

Could someone show me the way I can archive that result?

Comment: What is your SQL Server Version?

Comment: i'm using SQL server 2012, and i need to parse the result to json as well

Comment: `FOR JSON` is not supported with your currrent version of SQL Server (2012). What is the actual SQL Server version and what is the expected output?

Comment: i want my result to be a json string so i can parse it to list object like this                          
{Department = 1, EmployeeNames = ['A', 'B']}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use use `string_agg()` :

```
select DepartmentId, string_agg(EmployeeName, ',')
from EmployeeTable
group by DepartmentId;
```

For older version, you can do :

```
select et.DepartmentId,
       stuff((select concat(',', ett.EmployeeName)
              from EmployeeTable ett 
              where et.DepartmentId = ett.DepartmentId
              for xml path('')
              ), 1, 2, ''
            ) 
from (select distinct DepartmentId from EmployeeTable) et;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following query using `STUFF()` function and `FOR XML`.

```
SELECT DepartmentId, EmployeeName = 
    STUFF((SELECT ', ' + EmployeeName
           FROM MyTable b 
           WHERE b.DepartmentId = a.DepartmentId
          FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 2, '')
FROM MyTable a
GROUP BY DepartmentId
```

Live [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=98d78e6c51869a806f5de3f4ffe7c721) demo.

[image]

Comment: Hi, your solution works very well, but i need to parse that result to json later, could you show me some workaround using for json path?